# Remove left bar navigation from custom module via layout XML

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I have 2 modules Blog and Recipe.

Blog module has left navigations :

- ***Recent posts***
- ***Most views***
- ***Categories***

configured in as:

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\mageplaza_betterblog.xml**

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="mageplaza_betterblog/sidebar" name="post.list.right" as="post_list_right" before="-">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mageplaza_betterblog/general/sidebar_right">
                <template>mageplaza_betterblog/sidebar.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="mageplaza_betterblog/sidebar" name="post.list.left" as="post_list_left" before="-">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mageplaza_betterblog/general/sidebar_left">
                <template>mageplaza_betterblog/sidebar.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

In my Recipe module, I have left sidebar links as :

- ***Recipe Categories***
- ***Latest Recipes***

configured as :

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\magenshop\recipe.xml**

```
 <reference name="left">


        <block type="core/template" name="recipe_sidebar_newest" after="-">
            <action ifconfig="magenshoprecipe/general/shownewest" method="setTemplate"><template>magenshop/recipe/recipe_sidebar_newest.phtml</template></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/template" name="recipe_sidebar_popular" after="-">
            <action ifconfig="magenshoprecipe/general/showpopular" method="setTemplate"><template>magenshop/recipe/recipe_sidebar_popular.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="core/template" name="recipemenuleftsidebar" before="-" template="magenshop/recipe/menusidebar.phtml" />
        <!-- <remove name="post_list_left" /> -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>post_list_left</name></action>
    </reference>
```

Now I need to remove all the 3 left sidebar links from 'Blog' module which is conflicting with my recipe module.

ie) In Recipe module, I'm getting the links of Blog module as well.

I had tried to remove the Blog links in **`recipe.xml`** as:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>post_list_left</name></action>
```

But still the links are not getting removed.

Comment: Are you sure your layout is called from base theme Instead of your custom theme ? @Sachin S

Answer (score 3):

Ok thanks, found the problem,

I used

```
<remove name="post_list_left" />
```

in the right place, ie) in my scenario in the category page ie)

```
<recipe_category_index>
```